# 500 internal server error when editing a php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Involved in refining the app, found a bug in the back end, connected through FileZilla, replaced the line in the file and now:

```
2016-03-23 18:38:51.878 Social_Event[984:485926] Error      Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0., NSUnderlyingError=0x175d4010 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1bb17800> { URL: http://....compute.amazonaws.com/ws/user/driverstatus } { status code: 500, headers {
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 1396;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Wed, 23 Mar 2016 15:37:17 GMT";
Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14";
} },      NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://....compute.amazonaws.com/ws/user/driverstatus, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<
```

Function driverstatus not touched. The client accesses this file when you login, but when calling this function breaks down. Returned the original file, the error persists. The access rights of the file are the same as the others in this folder, the encoding using Sublime while maintaining set UTF-8 without bom.

```
function driverstatus()
{

    $iUserID = intVal($this->input->get_post("iUserID"));
    $status = $this->input->get_post('status');

    $sql = "UPDATE  `ridehost`.`tbl_user` SET  `onlineornot` = '$status' WHERE  `tbl_user`.`iUserID` = " . $iUserID . ";";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $responseData['status'] = "0";

    $responseData['data'] = array();

    $responseData['message'] = "Updated Successfully";

    je($responseData);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to reconnect?

Comment: With the information given, it's hard to tell. Check your PHP/Apache error logs for more information. If it's not there, turn on error_reporting and try again.

Comment: It's mobile app. Not web. I don't know how to check errors with error_reporting when It's called from mobile app.